# In the Dicee app both dice aren't functioning as expected

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm following along with one of Angela Yu's courses, I've been copying her step by step and both of our code is identical however when she runs this in the simulator the first die increases from 1 and the second die decreases from 5 however when I run this the second die doesn't change at all, please let me know if i'm missing something here!

[Image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A8P8c.png)

Comment: Check if `diceImageView2` is actually connected to the right image view in the storyboard ?

Comment: Thank you, I went over the storyboard and fixed the images. Please submit as an answer so I can accept it!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the looks of things, code and logic wise everything seems to be in order.

Most probably `diceImageView2` is not wired up properly as an outlet from your storyboard so that would be the first place I'd check.